# REGEX - Regular Expression pattern matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a regex pattern that I've got to match. It should match the first three characters exactly and any other integer w/ alphabet combination like this:

```
ch_1q2ew34sdfsadf334f43tf4y6y, or ch_1343ggrgr or asdfasdf2234234
```

I've got this so far, it works but I want to make sure I'm doing this right:

```
/([c])+([h])+([_])+[\w\d\._%+-]+/
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct but small changes in the syntax:

```
/ch_[\w\d._%+-]+/
```

- No need to put single character in `[ ]` and `+` here means match one or more characters.. i dont think you want to put that..
- No need to escape `.` inside character set..
- `( )` is a capture group and content captured inside a capture group can be back referenced with `\1`, `\2`, etc.. Use if you want to capture and dont if not required..

Comment: This regex did it **@karthik**! thanks for the help!